# Problem with a query in custom posts

Tags: custom-post-types, mysql

I'm making a search form to select available rooms.
I have a custom post for the rooms called "Products" and a post meta value called "availability" (format: Y-m-d).
And I want to find all rooms available from a certain date in my form: MyDate_a.

This is the code I use:

```
SELECT wposts.*
FROM $wpdb->posts wposts, $wpdb->postmeta wpostmeta
WHERE wposts.ID = wpostmeta.post_id
AND wpostmeta.meta_key = 'availability'
AND wpostmeta.meta_value >= $MyDate_a
AND wposts.post_status = 'publish'
AND wposts.post_type = 'products'
ORDER BY wpostmeta.meta_value DESC
```

But it seems that it select all the rooms, even if `$MyDate_a` is, lets say, 2013-03-30 and availability is 2013-04-01.

Comment: is there a reason you're not using [`WP_Query`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) for this?

Answer (score 0):

Like the commentor say, couldn't you use `WP_Query` for this?

```
$results = new WP_Query(array(
    'post_type' => 'products',
    'meta_query' => array(
        'key' => 'availability',
        'value' => $MyDate_a,
        'compare' => '='
    ),
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'orderby' => 'meta_value'
));
```